# New to PHP | How do I add a string that says "No file" is user does not attach a file on a php form submission?

Tags: php, email

the code below is of a web form. When a user submits, the user will receive an auto-generated email with a confirmation of their submission, and the department will receive an email with the data from that form submission. My question is this:

The form owner currently receives user submission data in this arraignment

```
You have received a new message from [NAME] 
My inquiry is about: [INSERT CATEGORY]
email address:[INSERT EMAIL] 
phone number:[INSERT #]
File Type: 
File Name: 
Date Stamp: December 21, 2021 4:03:54 pm 
Comments: [INSERT COMMENTS]
```

Currently, if the user submits the form without a file attachment, the return email shows the File type and File name as empty whitespace. I want to say "No file" on both "File type" and "File name". How do I do this?

Due to the sensitive nature of my workplace, I'm afraid I can only share limited code...any and all help is appreciated!

```
    date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
    $subj = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $comm = $_POST['comments'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $FiName = $_POST['FiName'];
    $tstamp = date("F j, Y   g:i:s a");


                $fileSize = 0;
 
$allowed = array("image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document","application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet","application/pdf","application/msword","application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text","application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet","text/plain");
 
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
                $file_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; //returns the mimetype
                $FiName = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
               
  if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
                  $error_message = 'Only jpg, gif, and pdf files are allowed.';
                  $error = 'yes';
                  header('Location: contact_IAD_F.shtml?invalid file type');
                }
}             
 

    $email_subject = 'Contact by: ' . $name . ' - ' . $subj;
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from $name.<br>".
    "My inquiry is about: $type<br>".
    "email address: $email<br>".
    "phone number: $phone<br>".
    "File Type: $file_type<br>".
    "File Name: $FiName<br>".
    "Date Stamp: $tstamp<br>". 
    "Comments:\n $comm<br>";
```

Comment: Look at how your code tests to see if a file has been uploaded, and sets various variables if it has.  You want to do something in the case that test fails, right? https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php

Comment: `if(is_array($_FILES))` is not the correct way to check for a successful file upload - even if your form did not even contain a file upload field at all, this will be an empty array. Your script should check if `$_FILES['attachment']` is set, and if so, what its `error` property contained.